How do I build the Cute Chess GUI on Windows 10?
Cute Chess is written in C++ using the Qt framework. How do I build the Cute Chess GUI on Windows 10?
I tried three methods to program this and failed three times.
(1) Cute Chess has provided instructions to build on Windows and Ubuntu (https://github.com/cutechess/cutechess/wiki/Building-from-source).
I can build it on Ubuntu by following the instructions without a problem.
However, when I do it with the same code on windows, it doesn't work.
I have installed Qt creator 5.15.2. When I open project in Qt creator, choose Cmakelist in the cutechess folder, and click Build - Build project "cutechess".
I get the errors:

D:\software\chessGUIsourcecode\cutechess\projects\lib\src\engineconfiguration.cpp:-1:
error: undefined reference to EngineConfiguration::timeoutScaleMin' D:\software\chessGUIsourcecode\cutechess\projects\lib\src\engineconfiguration.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to EngineConfiguration::timeoutScaleMax'
:-1: error: collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

But it is the same code built on Ubuntu.
(2) I found another instruction to build Cute Chess on GitHub (https://github.com/ianfab/fishtest/wiki/Build-cutechess-with-Qt5-static).
It uses MSYS2 MinGW. I tried it and it doesn't work either.
I copied the bash script to the MSYS2 64 console.
pacman -S --noconfirm git make zip mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-x86_64-jasper mingw-w64-x86_64-zstd mingw-w64-x86_64-qt5-static

git clone https://github.com/cutechess/cutechess.git
cd cutechess

git fetch -p --tags --all
tag=$(git describe --tags `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1`)
git checkout $tag -b latest

git log --oneline -n 5 > ../cutechess.git.log
/mingw64/qt5-static/bin/qmake.exe -config release
make -j 4
strip projects/cli/cutechess-cli.exe
strip projects/gui/cutechess.exe
zip -j9 ../cutechess-cli-win-64bit.zip COPYING projects/cli/cutechess-cli.exe

Error message:

make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
C:\tools\msys64\mingw64\bin\strip.exe:
'projects/cli/cutechess-cli.exe': No such file
C:\tools\msys64\mingw64\bin\strip.exe: 'projects/gui/cutechess.exe':
No such file
zip warning: name not matched: projects/cli/cutechess-cli.exe   adding: COPYING (deflated 66%)

I searched the internet about "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found". Someone suggested to copy make.exe to the folder. I tried, and it doesn't work.
(3) I also tried to build it with Visual Studio 2022 and this resulted in a lot of errors.
Can someone give me a suggestion?

Thanks for the editing, @SecretAgentMan.

I found a bash script to build it on github. It works. The link is https://github.com/ppigazzini/static-cutechess-cli.
